# Get uniques array elements without using array_unique

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have the following array:

```
$array = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10 ];
```

I'm trying to get all unique elements and push them to this array:

```
$newArray = [];
```

I've tried to go through the elements with for loop and check if the current element is equal to the next. Here's how:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    if ($array[$i] == $array[$i + 1]) {
        continue;
    }
    $array[$i] = $newArray;
}
```

If the current element is equal to the next, continue with the next iteration. If not equal, push it to the `$newArray` array.
I got the following exception:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 14
>   On this line:

```
if ($array[$i] == $array[$i + 1]) {
```

Any ideas why this happens ?

Comment: Yes. Your array has 14 elements, with offsets 0 through 13.

Comment: So, uh, why can't you use `array_unique()`?

Comment: @Phylogenesis now it's working but when var_dumping the array, the last element is missing. Any ideas how to fix that ?

Comment: You should use different indexes for both arrays. A foreach loop may be more appropriated in your case

Comment: Can you show example ?

Comment: Using your algorithm, you *always* need to add the final element of the array to the list of 'unique's.

Comment: See [this example](https://www.ideone.com/XFobid).

Comment: Thanks for explanations :)

Comment: Ok i'll adit an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs because your array `$array` contains 14 elements, (maximum offset is 13). In your `for` loop, `$i` has a maximum value of 13 (`count($array) - 1`), but at the last iteration, you try to compare `$array[$i]` (=`$array[13]`) to `$array[$i + 1]` (=`$array[14]`), and the offset 14 is not defined.

The **simplest** way to proceed :

```
<?php

$array = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
$newArray = [];

foreach($array as $value){
    if (!in_array($value, $newArray))
        $newArray[] = $value;
}
```

This version still gets you uniques values of an array, even if a character is used twice and non-following (e.g : `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`).

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:

```
<?php
$array = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10];
$newArray = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    if(!empty($array[$i + 1])){
        if ($array[$i] == $array[$i + 1]) {
            continue;
        }
        $newArray[] = $array[$i];
    }
}
print_r($newArray);
?>
```

Hope it help you.

Comment: It's not working if i have the following array: $array = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10];

Any ideas why ?

Comment: Let's try with: `array_values(array_unique($array))`. It's worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
   <pre>
<?php
$array = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10 ];
$arr=array();
$arr2=array();
print_r($array);
$backwards = array_reverse($array);
$last_item = NULL;
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if($last_item === $value){
        array_push($arr, $value) ;
        echo $key."=>". $value."<br>";
    }else{
       array_push($arr2, $value) ; 
    }
   //  array_push($array, $value) ;
     $last_item = $value;
}
echo "Duplicate values<br>";
print_r($arr);
echo "Array without duplicate values <br>";
print_r($arr2);
?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array has 14 elements so offsets go from `0` to `13`. PHP just notice to you that the offset you try to access not exist.

Answer (score -1):

You have [set](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ds-set.php) in php. Just use it - you can check if item is there by `contains`. But in most languages you can pass array as input, and you will get unique entries.

## edit

See it was too complicated for someone. Please try this code:

```
<?php
$array = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10 ];
$set = new \Ds\Set();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    $set->add($array[$i])
}
$newArray = $set->toArray()
var_dump($newArray);
?>
```